# Fact Table with Different Update Schedules

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse

I have two sets of data with the same level of grainularity, for example invoice number.  Most of the data required is updated daily as we recognize the revenue for previous invoices.  However, some of this data is fed through a seperate costing system once a month and is then fed to the data warehouse with additional information.  Should I create one fact table that contains both sets of data, and then run an update on the fact table once a month when the other data is imported in, or should I create two fact tables because of the different update schedule.  The data is related, and many queries (~35%) will want information from both sets of data (when avaliable).  The system imports 30,000 rows a day into the fact table has about 38,000,000 rows in it, the monthly update would affect 660,000 rows.

Comment: It's unclear from your post whether you'll be creating duplicate entries. "Some of the data is fed through a costing system". Does that mean it DIDN'T make it into the DWH until after the costing system step or does ALL the data go to the DWH and SOME of the data is ALSO sent to the costing system?

Comment: There would be no duplication.  The numbers that are fed into the costing system would already be in the data warehouse and not reentered.  Only new data elements (facts) would be inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Providing that already existing measures are not modified in the second step, you could treat the fact table as an "accumulating snapshot".
The table describes processes with a definitive start and the end -- kind of workflows. Look it up in Kimball's Data Warehouse Toolkit or just Google "Kimball accumulating snapshot fact table".

Comment: That looks like the a great match for what I am doing, thanks.